# How can I integrate Woocommerce into an Android Application?

Tags: java, android, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I am developing a mobile application for a client's Woocommerce website.

I am new to Woocommerce but I know that in order to manage it from a third party application I need to use their REST API. I have viewed their documentation but it does not seem to be very helpful. I have already activated the API in the Woocommerce settings on the website.

**With this application I *need* to be able to:**

Authenticate user-supplied credentials

View and manipulate account information

Manage a persistent cart between the app and the website

Make purchases

How can I integrate the API so that I can perform the above functions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Are you still looking for your answer or have you found your solution ?

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this??

Comment: @Nishith Have you find any solution? I have also stuck at same issue.

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal Have you find any solution? I have also stuck at same issue.